# Pipe Read Processing

Tags: linux, pipe

I have to get input from a user, put that into a pipe(in the parent process) then I have to process the string in the child. All uppercase letters need to be lowercase and all lowercase letters must be uppercase. My issue is with the output of the pipe. My code will only change the letter case of the first character in the string and I am not sure why. The child pipe is reading through all the characters (at least it appears to be). I was hoping someone could tell me why this wont process each character.

```
while (read(pfd[0], &buf, strlen(cmd)) > 0){
    if(buf >= 'a' && buf <= 'z'){
        buf = toupper(buf);
    }
    else{
        buf = tolower(buf);
    }
}

write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, strlen(cmd));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making two common mistakes.

(1) `read` does not buffer for you so you are not guaranteed to get len bytes (i.e.strlen(cmd) in your case.).  `read` will return whatever number of bytes it has available *up to* the length you specify but it can and often will return less.  So you want to change your read loop to reflect that.

(2) buf is presumably a char array.  You are always changing the first byte and only the first byte.  You need to iterate over the all the bytes you just read.

So putting it all together, something like

```
while ((bytesread = read(pfd[0], &buf, strlen(cmd))) > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesread; ++i)
    {
        if(buf[i] >= 'a' && buf[i] <= 'z')
            buf[i] = toupper(buf[i]);
        else
            buf[i] = tolower(buf[i]);              
    }

    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, bytesread);
}
```

Comment: that makes sense but buf is defined as         char buf; it isnt an array or a pointer.

Comment: also, I just changed the definition of buf to be an array and it all works perfectly. Hopefully I am not told it is required to be a single char and not an array!

Comment: Well if you really need to read into a single byte then what you originally had should work.  All you need to do is to change it to read a single byte per read rather than strlen(cmd) bytes.  But honestly that's a little nuts efficiency wise.